# Firefox v21 Support of Flexbox align-self?

Tags: firefox, alignment, flexbox

What is the Firefox v21 Support of Flexbox align-self? Any alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

align-self will be be enabled by default in Firefox 22.  In Firefox 21, it's disabled by default, using an about:config pref; that pref was [turned on](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=841876) in Firefox 22.

Answer (score 2):

The `align-self` property is called `flex-item-align` in the March 2012 Flexbox draft (only IE10 implements this version) and does not exist at all in the 2009 Flexbox draft.

Firefox versions that use the `-moz-` prefix follow the 2009 draft.  Firefox versions that do not have a prefix follow the standard draft.

Comment: What versions folow the standard? How about v21?

Comment: If you're using `display: -moz-box`, that's from 2009.  If you're using `display: flex`, that's from the standard draft.